# Disable automatic updates in Outlook 2013 Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I often update my Outlook 2013 Calendar events manually (for instance, changing the meeting location to a more obvious name instead of the confusing company-applied label) but the system overwrites my changes nightly noting "Your meeting was found to be out of date and has been automatically updated." Is there a way to disable this function?

Comment: One "fix" may be to disable the calendar repair assistant with PowerShell: `Set-Mailbox -Identity tony@contoso.com -CalendarRepairDisabled $true`.

Answer (score 0):

Try totally exit Outlook client and directly modify the calendar events on the web mail.

If it only occurs on Outlook client, please restart Outlook in safe mode and make calendar changes to have a try:  exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook /safe and then press Enter.

Besides, some third-party devices used to sync and manage Exchange calendar. Usually, some issues may be caused by some devices used for Exchange ActiveSync service. Have you also configured your account on mobile device? If yes, exit these application.